# Encryption & Decryption for Mobile Webservice

Tags: java, javascript, ios, objective-c, encryption

I'm working on a mobile App which is to be build in Android (Native)  , iOS (Native) & PhoneGap. For security I'm already using SSL, but as per client requirement another encryption is to be implemented in all webservices( Mobile end and Server) . But I'm unable to implement encryption which works well in Java, Objective-C and JavaScript.

I could manage to get AES-256 working in all the platforms , but it works very slow in Android. Library used for the same was RNCryptor.

Can you please suggest me any Encryption/Decryption library which is compatible along at least Java & Objective-C.

Comment: If its only slow in Android, its clearly an issue with that implementation not the cipher itself.  Try a different library?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Do you suggest something which works across different platforms, because most of the libraries doesn't give the same result across Android & iOS or doesn't work at all.

Comment: OK, they don't trust https (SSL/TLS) but are willing to trust an encryption scheme developed by someone who is not steeped in cryptography/encryption? WOW! Do this: pin the certificate in the app to avoid man-in-the-Middle (MITM) attacks and then do anything that they will accept for the encryption because **it does not matter**, https is providing the security.

Comment: SSL/TLS covers security **in transit**, so is the additional encryption scheme for data **at rest** on the device/server?

Comment: The question is about encryption and compatibility which suggest data in transit. Data at rest on the server is the server's responsibility. Data at rest on the mobile device is easily accomplished with `NSDataWritingOptions` options.

Answer (score 0):

AES-256 a correct choice and should not be a performance problem. Most cpu chips include special instructions to allow faster implementations, Apple ARM chips do as do may Intel chips. If you are going to claim that encryption is slow for an implementation you need to supply test times for all platforms, generate them and post them.

Obtaining the same results from encryption, AES-256 in this case, is simply supplying the exact same inputs with the exact required lengths and exact same options--that is all.

Providing secure encryption is more than just a key, data and an AES-256 library. There needs to be an iv, if the key is week it needs to be extended, passwords are generally extended with PBKDF2 or it's like. These require more information to be added to the encrypted data that is passed. There is also data padding such as PKCS#7. RNCryptor handles all this but for interoperability requires the other-end to use the same scheme. Then there is the issue of securing the encryption key and exchanging it with the other-side.